# Dynamically update select after changing previous select value using AJAX

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, jsp, jakarta-ee

I am aware that this is a recurring question, for all web programming languages. I have spent five hours trying to apply solutions found here without success, which is why I write this question.

What I want:

- I have two selectors, both when loading the page are filled with information directly from the database successfully.
- If I select an option from the first selector (selectSchraubfall) I want the second selector (selectWorkplace) to update, showing only those possible results for the first selector.

What I did:

- Created the selectors inside the jsp getting the information from a servlet that executes a sql query ✔.
- Created the onChange event listener for the first selector ✔.
- Created a js function with an Ajax call to make a new query from the controller and get a filtered list of options for the second select ✔.
- Inside the success function I tried to inject the result of the Ajax call into the second select via .html(), it does not work. How can I inject JSTL? In other words, how can I inject the content of wpFilteredList in selectWorkplace? ✕

What I tried:

- Using JSON -> Didn't work ✕
- Using JAVA scriplets inside the JSP -> Didn't work ✕

JSP

html:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md">
        <label style="font-size: 20px;">Schraubfall ID: </label>
        <select id="selectSchraubfall" name="selectSchraubfall" form="formResult" class="form-control" >
            <option>Select ID</option>
            <c:forEach items="${screwdriverlist}" var="screwdriverlist">
                <option><c:out value="${screwdriverlist.screwdriverid}" /></option>
            </c:forEach>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md">
        <label style="font-size: 20px;">Workplace: </label>
        <select id="selectWorkplace" name="selectWorkplace" form="formResult" class="form-control">
            <option>Select workplace</option>
            <c:forEach items="${workplaceList}" var="workplaceList">
                <option><c:out value="${workplaceList.workplacename}" /></option>
            </c:forEach>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var options="";
$("#selectSchraubfall").on('change',function(){
    var value=$(this).val();
    resultSelectValue('Schraubfall', value);
});



function resultSelectValue(columnName, value) {
    // Statements
    var params = {};
        params.colname = columnName;
        params.valuecol = value;

    $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: 'ResultSelectValuesController',
            data: params,
            success: function (data) {
                var workplaceArray = [];
                $("#selectWorkplace").empty().html();

                <c:forEach items="${wpFilteredList}" var="wpFilteredList">
                    //<option value="${wpFilteredList.name}"></option>
                    workplaceArray.push('"${wpFilteredList.name}"');
                </c:forEach>

                $("#selectWorkplace").html(workplaceArray); //I know this is not correct but how can I do something similar using the wpFilteredList?

            },
            error : function(ex) {
                swal("Error", "Error loading workplace info " + ex.Message, "error");
            }
        });
}
```

Java (ResultSelectValuesController)

```
@Override
public void processMethodGET(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
        String colname = request.getParameter("colname");
        String valuecol = request.getParameter("valuecol");

        if(colname.contains("Schraubfall")) {
            //GET WORKPLACES
            workplacesfilteredlist = wcdao.workplacesListFilter(colname, valuecol);
            request.setAttribute("wpFilteredList", workplacesfilteredlist);
        }

        request.getRequestDispatcher("/Views/Results/ResultPage.jsp").forward(request, response);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        processError(e, request, response);
    }
}
```

Comment: you can use `gson` here, i.e:  convert your list to gson send it to ajax call and then loop through it using `for` loop.

Comment: That is what I'm trying right now without success :(

Comment: what is not working ? did you got any error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below block is JSTL server side interpolation. Javascript can't process this syntax.
You need to replace below JSTL code with javascript version which pushes the data from ajax requests response to workplaceArray.

```
                <c:forEach items="${wpFilteredList}" var="wpFilteredList">
                    //<option value="${wpFilteredList.name}"></option>
                    workplaceArray.push('"${wpFilteredList.name}"');
                </c:forEach>
```

The code below is adds new data to the select element as option elements. You need to replace data as your response type.

```
data.forEach(workplace => {
    $('#selectWorkplace').append($('<option>', {
       value: workplace,
       text: workplace
    })
})
```

After the changes you don't need the below code anymore.

```
$("#selectWorkplace").html(workplaceArray);
```

Comment: I need to know your data response for writing the code.

Comment: You mean the expected result in (data) ?

If so, this is an example (list): 1RA, 1RP, 2RA, 2RP (this is the value I'm getting in the Java class, and this is what I want to send to the success: function (data))

Comment: yes please if you could write the result in the question like result is this from the ajax request.

Comment: I edited the comment below, let's say I just want to send a List of strings from the Java Controller class to the ajax success data.

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind help Berk Öztürk, finally I solved it in another way.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved the problem by myself, It worked using Gson. Basically I am returning an Array of Arrays and I manipulate the data as I want in the JSP.

The code now:

JSP

```
function resultSelectValue(columnName, value) {
// Statements
var params = {};
    params.colname = columnName;
    params.valuecol = value;

$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'ResultSelectValuesController',
        data: params,
        success: function (data) {
            $( "#selectWorkplace" ).empty();
            $( "#selectSchraubfall").empty();

            var htmlWorkplace = "<option>Seleccionar Workplace</option>";
            var htmlsf = "<option>Todos los Schraubfalls</option>";
            for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                for(j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++){
                    alert(data[i][j]);
                    if(i == 0) {
                        htmlWorkplace += "<option>"+data[i][j]+"</option>";
                    }
                    if(i == 1){
                        if(data[i][j] != 'null' &&  data[i][j] != null){
                            htmlsf += "<option>"+data[i][j]+"</option>";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            $( "#selectWorkplace" ).html(htmlWorkplace);
            $( "#selectSchraubfall").html(htmlsf);
```

JAVA

```
@Override
public void processMethodGET(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {

        response.setContentType("application/json");
        String colname = request.getParameter("colname");
        String valuecol = request.getParameter("valuecol");

        if(colname.contains("Atornillador")) {

            //GET WORKPLACES
            wpfilteredlist = wcdao.workplacesListFilter(colname, valuecol);

            //GET SF
            sffilteredlist = sfdao.SFListFiltered(colname, valuecol);


            ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> listGet = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

            ArrayList<String> wpList = new ArrayList<String>();
            ArrayList<String> sfLista = new ArrayList<String>();



            for (int i = 0; i < wpfilteredlist.size(); i++) {
                wpList.add(wpfilteredlist.get(i).getName());
            }

            for(int i = 0; i < sffilteredlist.size(); i++) {
                sfList.add(sffilteredlist.get(i).getSfname());
            }

            listGet.add(wpList);
            listGet.add(sfList);

            Gson gson = new Gson();
            JsonElement element = gson.toJsonTree(listGet);
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            out.print(element);

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        processError(e, request, response);
    }
}
```